# Unix shell script retrieving multiple files at different timings

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have below requirement:

I have one java process it writes lot of files into unix folder everyday,But below files  needs sftp to different folder using Unix Shell Script

TestSD20121016.csv (It writes file into unix folder at 16:00P.M everyday)
TestSP20121016.csv(It writes file into unix folder at 17:00P.M everyday)

Script I written as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Parameters
# sftp_file_uploads.sh remoteServer functionalId
#------------------------------------------------------------------------

REMOTE_SERVER=$1
FUNCTIONAL_ID=$2
FILE_TO_UPLOAD= ls -lrt TESTSD`date "+%Y%m%d"`*.CSV  | awk '/TEST/{ f=$NF };END{ print f }'


#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create sftp script
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
rm -f /var/tmp/SFTP_FILE_UPLOAD
echo "lcd $3" > /var/tmp/SFTP_FILE_UPLOAD
echo "cd $5" >> /var/tmp/SFTP_FILE_UPLOAD
echo "put $FILE_TO_UPLOAD" >> /var/tmp/SFTP_FILE_UPLOAD
echo "bye" >> /var/tmp/SFTP_FILE_UPLOAD



#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Do sftp
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo " Before SFTP " > /tmp/FILE_UPLOAD_LOG
/usr/bin/sftp -B /var/tmp/SFTP_FILE_UPLOAD $2@$1 1>/var/tmp/sftp.log 2>&1

result=$?
if [ $result -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "SFTP completed successfully"
else
  echo "FAILED to SFTP"
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Problem is script is able to take file TestSD20121016.csv but not file TestSP20121016.csv,I dont know how to write above script to do sftp second file also.

Regards,

Chaitu

Answer (score 0):

how about
add line:

```
FILE_TO_UPLOAD2= ls -lrt TESTSP`date "+%Y%m%d"`*.CSV  | awk '/TEST/{ f=$NF };END{ print f }'
```

and line

```
echo "put $FILE_TO_UPLOAD2" >> /var/tmp/SFTP_FILE_UPLOAD
```

I think you know where should put right?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is a single character, you can replace it with an `?`, which tells it to match a single character (any character):

```
FILE_TO_UPLOAD= ls -lrt TESTS?`date "+%Y%m%d"`*.CSV  | awk '/TEST/{ f=$NF };END{ print f }'
```